# ComboBox ItemsSource from MarkupExtension SelectedItem out of sync

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, markup-extensions

I am struggling with the following.

I want to set a `ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` with a object collection provided from a `MarkupExtension`.

Such as:
`ItemsSource="{ex:ItemsSource ModelType=m:Category}"`
where `ItemsSource` is a class `ItemsSourceExtension` deriving from `MarkupExtension`.

Problem is that when doing so, the `ComboBox`'s `SelectedItem` is null although its binding source has a value.

[image: ComboBox Selected Item is null]
[image: ComboBox Selected Item is null]
I have tried a lot. Have tried deriving from `MarkupExtension` and also tried subclassing Binding to no avail.

I want to simulate the use of a standard Binding, where it works fine.

Such as: `ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Categories, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=v:DetailView}}"`

Result: [image: This is how it should be]

Comment: Keep in mind that the SelectedItem must compare equal to an element from the ItemsSource collection.

Comment: @Clemens I don't thing that that's the issue here as both (the Classic Binding extension and my MarkupExtension) are returning the very same List of objects.

Comment: @Clemens. You are 100% right, Finally figured it out. The ItemsSource object collection is of same type and same structure, but they where originating from different EntityFramework DbContext instances. Hence the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Finally figured it out. The `ItemsSource` object collection provided by the `MarkupExtension` were originating from different `EntityFramework` `DbContext` instances.